# Using spring-configuration without creating a spring dependency for your clients

Tags: java, spring

If I use spring configuration to construct an object, is it possible for me to instantiate that object for clients without requiring them to import my spring configuration?

If this can't be done, does one client using spring always necessitate any of its clients use spring?

If this can be done, what is the correct way to do it? Something like this...

Library code:

```
public MyFactory() {

   @Autowired
   InitializedObject obj

   public getInstance() {
     return obj;
   }
}
```

Client code:

```
   import com.code.package.something.myfactory.MyFactory;

...

   InitializedObject obj = MyFactory.getInstance();
```

Comment: Also, instead of `@Autowired`, use `@Inject`

Answer (score 0):

One of the option is to avoid Spring annotations altogether, working only with spring configuration files to have constructor or setter based injection. That way your classes become independent of Spring code and your client can use your code as long as he provide the dependencies correctly using factory or whatever.

Comment: This sounds like exactly what I want to know. Can you go into some more detail about what that means to have only constructor or setter-based injection? Any code samples?

Comment: By quick googling I found this link: https://sites.google.com/site/arjunwebworld/Home/programming/spring-dependency-injection. Go through the first part of it without annotation and that should work

Answer (score 0):

Autowiring dependency is done by the Spring container. If there's none, then it won't get autowired. You need to either ensure the client has a Spring container configured properly to autowire your dependency, or setup one yourself (eg: using `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`)